# How to extract video from corrupt rar file and make it playable

Tags: osx-mountain-lion, rar

I have a big file compressed in split rar archives. There are 68 archives, named .rar, .r01, .r02, ... And the problem is that .r36 is corrupted `Unexpected end of archive`. I've looked around and I have found nothing.

There is no way to repair the file.

And now my question is if it's possible to *skip* the file. I mean, extract all files except the .r36. The result should be a big file with a small part of it corrupted, but it doesn't matter.

Is that possible? To *skip* a file from extraction. Because my main problem is that all the apps I've tried stop the task when they find the error.

Well, I'm under Mac OS X 10.8.2. I forgot to say that. But I can virtualize Linux or Windows or whatever you want without any problem.

**EDIT:** Well, there is an option in WinRAR: *keep broken files*, which gives you the entire file except the part(s) which were broken.

But of you have a video file, the video player will only run well until the corrupt part. At that point it will be unplayable.

Is there any way you can play the rest of the video fter the corrupted part?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about UnRAR in OS X, but WinRAR's **Extraction** dialog has a **Keep broken files** option, which the Help file describes thus:

> **Keep broken files**
>
> WinRAR will not delete files which are not extracted properly, for example, when the archive is damaged (by default, WinRAR deletes such files). You can try to save part of the information from a broken file.

[image: 1]

A **Recovery Record** helps in situations like this, to allow recovery from corruption up to a certain extent.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it doesn't work. There is only one file. A video. And when WinRar founds the error it stops the extraction so I get a 3GB file instead of 7GB. What I want is to skip that damn part and extract the rest of the file. Besides there's no recovery record in the .rar file

Comment: I just tried with a split archive of a video (no recovery record), where I opened one of the parts in a hex editor and randomly deleted chunks of data. WinRAR displayed an error of course, but with that option on it extracted the file completely with a size equal to the original, leaving gaps in the middle. The video played fine till it got stuck and hung my player completely. If it didn't extract the complete file in your case (minus the missing data of course), guess the damage must be too extensive or something. Can't think of anything else that might help save a more tolerant extractor.

Comment: Well, that makes some sense. That's my problem. And I promise I've done it under Windows with WinRAR and the program didn't act as you said. I will try again, and answer you.

Comment: Ok, as you said the video stops at the point where the corrupt data are. I would like to play the rest. But I gess this is impossible. Thank you anyway.

Comment: So you managed after all to save the complete file, including the part after the damage? Which format is the video in? If you can find a way to repair its index it *may* be possible to skip the damaged part during playback.